# Angular: Iterate over nested object using resolver

Tags: angular, render, resolver

I have this resolver service for my admin module:

```
constructor(private userservice: UserService) { }

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any> {
    return this.userservice.getUserById(route.paramMap.get('id'));
  }
}
```

The fethed data in a detail component

```
export class AdminDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  user: any;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe((data:any) => {
      this.user=Array.of(data);
      console.log(this.user)
    });
  }
}
```

The routes of admin

```
const routes: Routes = [

  {path:'', component:AdminComponent},
  {
    path:'user/:id',
    component:AdminDetailComponent,
    resolve: {
      adminUser: UserResolverService
    }
  }
];
```

The HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" *ngFor="let u of user">
      {{u.username}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is the structure of the fetched data

```
[{…}]
0:
adminUser: {username: "spacecadet", password: "12345", id: 2}
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I've tried all I can remember but I cant get a loop for rendering the data. Can someone sort me out?

Comment: what error or bug are you getting

Comment: nothing, data doesnt appear. And if I don transform data into an array, I cant get iteration

Comment: what is the original structure of the data... it looks like it's already an array according to your post....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your init, you just need this...

```
this.user = data;
```

and in your ngFor, you need to access the properties correctly....

```
{{u.adminUser.username}}
```

Comment: but I need this: ` this.user=Array.of(data);`

Comment: it's odd that you need that. I'd need to know the original structure of the data and why you're tryign to force it to an array instead of just accessing it as a property.

Comment: if I dont transform it into an array I get an error

Comment: it sounds like it's an object to begin with but you force it into an array to use ngFor, when that's simply not needed. you can just set the object to user and access `{{user.adminUser.username}}` and wrap it in an `*ngIf="user"` to avoid errors. it doesn't make much sense to force things into arrays when you just want to access object properties in template.